# Do I need skins to drag a pulk on skis?

Tags: skiing

In a few weeks time I will be taking part in expedition skiing across Iceland. Our kit will be in pulks and we will be skiing with Nordic skis. Uphill I'm sure we'll need skins, but on the flatter sections, would grip wax provide enough traction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can get away with just grip wax on flatter sections, assuming the weight of the pull is not too much.  I regularly pull an infant in a similar configuration using just grip wax, even climbing small hills (legs akimbo), total weight is probably about 30lbs, but I know others with older kids that are pull closer to 50lbs.